# IIS - how to handle file permission problem

Tags: files, iis

Here is a generic error message, shown several times on each page :

> Warning: file_put_contents(temporary://fil25BC.tmp): failed to open stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in > file_unmanaged_save_data() (line 1935 of C:\inetpub\www-v2.3\includes\file.inc).

What can I do ?

EDIT
I stopped struggling with that problem by changing my temporary directory on this server
It was C:\Windows\temp (or C:\Windows\temp\drp-tmp)
It is now sites/default/files/drp-tmp
Note : on another server, the first setting is not giving warnings... Well, looks like I do not master that topic !
THANK YOU FOR your answers and attention

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.  This question is unfortunately a poor fit for the Q+A format used at this site. There are too many things that may possibly be wrong for us to list them, and impossible to narrow it down without having direct access to the site with debugging tools to pin down the cause. When you're further along in your debugging and have specific questions then please do ask them. Please see the [FAQ](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/on-topic) for more information about what kinds if questions can be asked here.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like issue is that Drupal is trying to write a temporary file somewhere it cannot write, like in the site's docroot...

Try running below commands using drush and make sure write access is available for temp directories..

```
~$ drush vget file_directory_temp

~$ drush vget file_temporary_path
```